# Concatenation of multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, concatenation, multiple-columns

I have three columns in my data frame:

| CaseID | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rohit | pandey |
| 2 |  | rai |
| 3 |  |  |

In the output, I am trying to add the fourth column and have values as LastName,FirstName

I have this Python code

```
df_ids['ContactName'] = df_ids[['LastName', 'FirstName']].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.values), axis=1)
```

But it appends the blank values also which something like below that I am able to get like below:

| CaseID | FirstName | LastName | ContactName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rohit | pandey | pandey, rohit |
| 2 |  | rai | , rai |
| 3 |  |  | , |

The expected output:

| CaseID | FirstName | LastName | ContactName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rohit | pandey | pandey, rohit |
| 2 |  | rai | rai |
| 3 |  |  |  |

Comment: Two choices.  (1) You will need to write a function for this and use `.apply`.  (2) Write three different transforms, using something like  `df[df['FirstName'] == '']` to select the rows to change.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for the reply. I am very new to python. I am learning all from google. Do you mind explaining a little bit more?

Comment: I don't know the performance but just change the `x.values` to `x[x != '']` should do it.  or `x[x.str.len() > 0]` to take care of None or NaN type of data.

Comment: @rohitpandey - Someone has added PySpark tag. Is it Pyspark or Pandas question?

Answer (score 1):

Someone has added PySpark tag. This is PySpark version:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_ids = df_ids.replace('', None)  # Replaces empty strings with nulls
df_ids = df_ids.withColumn('ContactName', F.concat_ws(', ', 'LastName', 'FirstName'))
df_ids = df_ids.fillna('')  # Replaces nulls back to empty strings

df_ids.show()
# +------+---------+--------+-------------+
# |CaseID|FirstName|LastName|  ContactName|
# +------+---------+--------+-------------+
# |     1|    rohit|  pandey|pandey, rohit|
# |     2|         |     rai|          rai|
# |     3|         |        |             |
# +------+---------+--------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easy way, using `apply`.  `apply` takes each row one at a time and passes it to the given function.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    [ 1, 'rohit', 'pandey' ],
    [ 2, '', 'rai' ],
    [ 3, '', '' ]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['CaseID', 'FirstName', 'LastName'] )

def fixup( row ):
    if not row['LastName']:
        return ''
    if not row['FirstName']:
        return row['LastName']
    return row['LastName'] + ', ' + row['FirstName']

print(df)
df['Contact1'] = df.apply(fixup, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   CaseID FirstName LastName
0       1     rohit   pandey
1       2                rai
2       3                   
   CaseID FirstName LastName       Contact1
0       1     rohit   pandey  pandey, rohit
1       2                rai            rai
2       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Two (actually 1 and a half) other options, which are very close to your attempt:

```
df_ids['ContactName'] = (
    df_ids[['LastName', 'FirstName']]
    .agg(lambda row: ', '.join(name for name in row if name), axis=1)
)
```

or

```
df_ids['ContactName'] = (
    df_ids[['LastName', 'FirstName']]
    .agg(lambda row: ', '.join(filter(None, row)), axis=1)
)
```

In both version the `''`s are filtered out:

1. Via a generator expression: The `if name` makes sure that `''` isn't allowed, because its truth value is `False` - try `print(bool(''))`.
2. By the built-in function [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) with the first argument set to `None`.